# why would my databse entries be coming up empty?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create new instances based off of the form below however when it saves, the database only saves the foreign key value and the order value but nothing else. Any Idea why?

models:

```
class danceType(models.Model):
    eventtype = models.ForeignKey(compType)
    dance_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    Price = models.FloatField(max_length = 7, null=True, blank=True )
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
      fields = ('field_2')
      return self.dance_name 


class dancer(models.Model):
    dancetype = models.ForeignKey(danceType)
    e_number = models.IntegerField(max_length = 4, null=True, blank=True)
    D1_first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    D1_last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    D1_email = models.EmailField(max_length = 20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    perform = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
```

View:

```
if request.method =='POST':

    sub_type = request.POST.get("form")
    dancetype = request.POST.get("dancetype")
    ext = request.POST.get("quantity")

    form = modelformset_factory(dancer, form=CompReg, extra=int(ext))
    productform = form(queryset = dancer.objects.none())

    if sub_type == "submitted":

        productform = form(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if productform.is_valid():
            for p in productform:
                dance=p.save(commit=False)
                dance.dancetype_id = 4
                dance.order = 1
                dance.save()
        else:
            der = "it didnt save"
```